# How to send HTTP request from action button in Push Notification when app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm currently working on an iOS app where I use node-apn to send push notifications. The app targets iOS 10 and above. So far, I've been able to:

1. Send push notifications.
2. Add action buttons to the notifications.
3. Send an HTTP request when an action button is pressed (but only when the app is running).

However, I'm struggling to send an HTTP request when the app is terminated and an action button is pressed.

Here's a current code:

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    var apnsToken: String?
    var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = .invalid

    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
        apnsToken = tokenParts.joined()
    }

    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didEnterBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)

        let buttonAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "accept",
                                                title: "Accept",
                                                options: [])

        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "message",
                                            actions: [buttonAction],
                                            intentIdentifiers: [],
                                            options: [])
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "YourAppIdentifierHere",
                                            binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        channel.setMethodCallHandler({
            (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            switch call.method {
            case "getAPNsToken":
                self.sendToken(result: result)
            default:
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
            }
        })

        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    @objc func didEnterBackground() {
        backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "AcceptAction") {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
            self.backgroundTask = .invalid
        }
        acceptAction()
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
        self.backgroundTask = .invalid
    }

    func acceptAction() {
    }

    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if response.actionIdentifier == "accept" {
            let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
            if let deviceId = userInfo["deviceId"] as? String {
                var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = .invalid
                backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask {
                    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
                    backgroundTask = .invalid
                }

                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    let url = URL(string: "YourServerURLHere")!
                    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                    request.httpMethod = "POST"
                    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                    let parameters: [String: Any] = ["roomId": deviceId]
                    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)

                    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
                        backgroundTask = .invalid

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completionHandler()
                        }
                    }
                    task.resume()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func sendToken(result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        if let token = self.apnsToken {
            result(token)
        } else {
            result("")
        }
    }
}
```

I initially searched for solutions on Google and also tried to improve my current code with GitHub Copilot. My expectation was to be able to send an HTTP request not only when the app is in the background but also when it is terminated.

Here's what I achieved and observed:

- What Worked:

  - Receiving push notifications in the background.
  - Sending an HTTP request when an action button is pressed while the app is in the background.
- What Didn't Work:

  - Sending an HTTP request when the app is terminated and an action button is pressed.

I was expecting that the same logic for sending an HTTP request would work even when the app is terminated, but it didn't. I can receive push notifications and add action buttons just fine, but the HTTP request part is not working when the app is terminated.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64134294/http-request-from-ios-push-notification-action-when-app-is-in-background?rq=2